# How to type text by cypress cy.type in <ion-input> Input type?

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3, automated-tests, cypress

< ion-input data-cy="email" type="email" class="border"  placeholder="EMAIL">

If I do 
  var typedText = 'test@email.com'

```
    cy.get('[data-cy=email]')
        .type(typedText,{ force: true })   
        .should('have.value',typedText)
```

the test run shows error like

CypressError: cy.type() failed because it requires a valid typeable element.

Answer (score 4):

var typedText = 'test@email.com'

```
    cy.get('[data-cy=type-email]>[data-cy=type-email]')
        .type(typedText)   
        .should('have.value',typedText)
```

OR

var typedText = 'test@email.com'

```
    cy.get('[data-cy=password]').children() 
        .type(typedText)   
        .should('have.value',typedText)
```

This worked for ionic.

Comment: children() is also working only syntax of that should be as

cy.get('[data-cy=password]').children()

Comment: cy.get('[data-cy=type-email]>[data-cy=type-email]') does not work for me using Ionic 6

Answer (score 2):

The [cypress documentation for the type() method](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/type.html#Tabindex) states that in order to use it in conjunction with a *non-input or non-textarea* you have to apply the tabindex attribute to the element you wish to type into.

They do not explain why that is and I have not worked with cypress myself. I hope this works for you.

Comment: Yes It do work but another problem occors that is.


CypressError: cy.type() can only be called on a single element. Your subject contained 2 elements.

And when I look into html generated by <ion-input> there are two input tags witn <ion-input> and <input>

Comment: From what I understand the attribute is currently applied to both elements which is why your subject contains two of them. In that case you will probably have to narrow down your results by modifying your selector so it only returns the *<input>* element. This could look something like this: **'input[data-cy=email]'**. You could also look into using the [.children()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/children.html#Syntax) command.

Comment: Thanks , I got an solution by understanding your point of child method.