# Angular Form with PrimeNg Editor -> how to test with Cypress.io

Tags: angular, editor, primeng, e2e-testing, cypress

How can I add Text in PrimeNg Editor with Cypress.io

```
it('Send Email', () => {
  cy.get('#email').type('info@bandbee.com');
  cy.get('#subject').type('test');
  cy.get('#description').type('check quill');
  cy.contains('Senden').click()
})
```

I got this error:

> CypressError: cy.type() failed because it requires a valid typeable element.

Here is my Html:

```
  <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-12 ui-lg-8">
        <p-editor id="description" [style]="{'min-height':'300px'}" placeholder="...Text hier"
                  formControlName="message">
          <p-header>

          <span class="ql-formats">
              <select class="ql-size">
                  <option value="small"></option>
                  <option selected></option>
                  <option value="large"></option>
                  <option value="huge"></option>
                </select>
          </span>
            <span class="ql-formats">
                  <select class="ql-font">
                  </select>
          </span>
            <span class="ql-formats">
                  <select class="ql-color">
                  </select>
               <select class="ql-background">
                  </select>
          </span>
            <span class="ql-formats">
              <button class="ql-bold" aria-label="Bold"></button>
              <button class="ql-italic" aria-label="Italic"></button>
              <button class="ql-underline" aria-label="Underline"></button>
             <button class="ql-strike" aria-label="Strike"></button>
          </span>
            <span class="ql-formats">
              <select class="ql-align">
                  </select>
      <button class="ql-clean" aria-label="Clean"></button>
          </span>
          </p-header>
        </p-editor>
      </div>
```

PrimeNg Editor ist based on Quill

Comment: Show us your html where #email is defined

Comment: Did you search the site for an answer? I think this will help you - https://stackoverflow.com/q/53061718/2342414

Comment: Please share your HTML code

Comment: Added HTML - any Ideas?

Comment: Any update on that?